# MacOS displaylink flux not working on external screens

Tags: macbook, f.lux, displaylink

I have an Apple M2 Macbook Pro and a dual external monitor setup with a DisplayLink manager adapter. When I try to enable f.lux on two external monitors the colors are not changing and it's always full brightness. However, on Mac's screen, it works... Does anyone know the workaround?

[image]

Comment: It can be a driver limitation.

Comment: It says it's a beta - report it to the developers.